# Communication between Global.asax and Controller on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if the title doesn't clear enough. Please edit if you want to.

I have created a listener (FileSystemWatcher) on Global.asax:

```
/// This ValueFromDB can dynamically changed.
private string path = ValueFromDB;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = path;
    watcher.Created += SomethingChanged;
}

void SomethingChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Do Something
    /// I want to notify current screen (Controller) via ajax/anything
}
```

I am sorry, I have two question after all.

1. This `ValueFromDB` can dynamically changed via user screen. How to refresh Global.asax without restart the application?
2. I want to notify current screen (Controller) via ajax/anything that can tell something has changed from listener (path folder).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would go for SignalR and Websockets. Then you can push the content that changed to the client. Doesn't even need a Controller.

Comment: never do that before, I'll try look into it.

Comment: A quick search gives you this post - https://logcorner.wordpress.com/2015/11/22/real-time-filewatcher-system-monitor-using-tpl-dataflow-asp-net-web-api-signalr-asp-net-mvc-and-angular-js/

Comment: thanks a lot @smoksnes